# Android IME - how to detect entering a View?

Tags: java, android, ime

I am trying to write a custom IME for the Android OS. However, I cannot figure out how to detect when the user is entering e.g. an `EditText`.

I have already tried overriding some of the `on...()` methods of `InputMethodService` to no avail.

The documentation hasn't been particularly helpful to me here, I'm having a hard time understanding the description of the `InputMethodService` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for documentation purposes: I found the answer myself.

When a view is entered, the `InputMethodService`'s `onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting)` method is called. If the `EditorInfo`'s `InputType` is != 0, the view is editable, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TextWatcher`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to find out when a user is entering text into an EditText. Otherwise, for any other view, you should be able to override the [`onFocusChanged`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) method.

Comment: How would I use that in an IME? Is there a way to automatically attach a TextWatcher to all EditTexts (or Editables) that are created by apps?